# trouble splitting and printing a text array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on  simple cookbook, the user inputs ingredients(text input) separated by commas, and when viewing that recipe off to the side in its own box it shows the ingredients. My trouble is I want to change the ingredient a, ingredient b, ingredient c list to
*ingredient a
*ingredient b ect.
in my console

```
 i = ("bread, milk, butter")
i.split.each { |n| puts "Current ingredient is: #{n}" }
```

gives me the output

- Current ingredient is: bread,
- Current ingredient is: milk,
- Current ingredient is: butter

When I try and implement this

```
<aside id= 'ingredients'>
  <strong>Ingredients:</strong>
  <ul>
    <li><%= @recipe.ingredients.split(',').each { |n| 
      puts "Current ingredient is: #{n}" } %></li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

I get the appropriate box but the output is "["spaghetti noodles", " meatballs", " sauce"]"

If anyone has any thoughts on this I'd appreciate it!

Comment: you need `.map` instead of `.each` and remove the `puts`, which returns nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things...

1. `puts` displays things in the console not the html
2. `<%=` displays the results of `@recipe.ingredients.split(',')` which is an array.

Need to iterate outside the `<li>` and display the items...

```
<aside id= 'ingredients'>
  <strong>Ingredients:</strong>
  <ul>
    <% @recipe.ingredients.split(',').each do |n| %>
      <li>
         <%= "Current ingredient is: #{n}" %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

Note that it is

```
<% @recipe.ingredients.split(',').each do |n| %>
```

not

```
<%= @recipe.ingredients.split(',').each do |n| %>
```

Comment: In general it's not great to be parsing data in your view code. You may consider doing the `ingredients.split(',')` as a method in the Recipe model (or a presenter) or parsing it on assignment and storing it in a structured way (e.g. `array` or `jsonb` type).

Comment: The "displays things to the console" is true, but it also should yield its `nil` in the html.  `puts` returns `nil`, while producing output to (usually) standard out.  Since the return is used for the html, and `to_s` is called, an empty string should be produced there.